# Correct way to convert old SIGNAL and SLOT to new style?

Tags: python, syntax, pyqt4, pyqt5, signals-slots

I'm currently trying to convert an old python program from Python 2 to Python 3, and update from PyQt4 to PyQt5. The application uses the old style signal and slots that are not supported under PyQt5. I have figured out most of what needs to be done, but below are a few lines that I can't seem to get working:

```
self.emit(SIGNAL('currentChanged'), row, col)
self.emit(SIGNAL("activated(const QString &)"), self.currentText())
self.connect(self,SIGNAL("currentChanged(const QString&)"), self.currentChanged)
```

The top two lines, I have no idea where to start since they don't seem to be attached to anything. The last example I'm not quite sure what to do with (`const QString &`).

I'm not entirely sure how to approach these, and I'm still learning python, but any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The documentation doesn't really seem to go into depth on these cases, at least in a way that I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact answer to this will depend on what kind of object `self` is. If it is a Qt class that already defines those signals, then the new-style syntax would be this:

```
self.currentChanged[int, int].emit(row, col)
self.activated[str].emit(self.currentText())
self.currentChanged[str].connect(self.handleCurrentChanged)
```

However, if any of those *aren't* pre-defined, you would need to define custom signals for them, like this:

```
class MyClass(QWidget):
    # this defines two overloads for currentChanged
    currentChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal([int, int], [str])
    activated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.currentChanged[str].connect(self.handleCurrentChanged)   

    def handleCurrentChanged(self, text):
        print(text)
```

The old-style syntax allowed custom signals to be emitted dynamically (i.e. without defining them first), but that is not possible any more. With the new-style syntax, custom signals must always be explicitly defined.

Note that, if there is only one overload defined for a signal, the selector can be omitted:

```
    self.activated.emit(self.currentText())
```

For more information, see these articles in the PyQt Docs:

- [Support for Signals and Slots (PyQt5)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html)
- [Old-style Signal and Slot Support (PyQt4)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html)
- [New-style Signal and Slot Support (PyQt4)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)

**EDIT**:

For your actual code, you need to make the following changes for the `currentChanged` signals:

1. In *Multibar.py* (around line 30):

   This defines a custom signal (because `QWidget` does not have it):

   ```
   class MultiTabBar(QWidget):
       # add the following line
       currentChanged = pyqtSignal(int, int)
   ```
2. In *Multibar.py* (around line 133):

   This emits the custom signal defined in (1):

   ```
   # self.emit(SIGNAL('currentChanged'), row, col)
   self.currentChanged.emit(row, col)
   ```
3. In *ScWindow.py* (around line 478):

   This connects the signal defined in (1):

   ```
       # self.connect(self.PieceTab,SIGNAL("currentChanged"),self.pieceTabChanged)
       self.PieceTab.currentChanged.connect(self.pieceTabChanged)
   ```
4. In *ItemList.py* (around line 73):

   The `QFileDialog` class [already defines this signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#currentChanged), and there is only one overload of it. But the name of the slot must be changed, because it is shadowing the built-in signal name (which has become an attribute in the new-style syntax). So the connection should be made like this:

   ```
       # self.connect(self,SIGNAL("currentChanged(const QString&)"),self.currentChanged)
       self.currentChanged.connect(self.onCurrentChanged)
   ```
5. In *ItemList.py* (around line 78):

   This renames the slot for the connection made in (4):

   ```
       # def currentChanged(self, file):
       def onCurrentChanged(self, file):
   ```

Comment: I tried using self.currentChanged[int, int].emit(row, col) initially, but kept receiving an error that the object (QWidget) has no attribute 'currentChanged', but the old line self.emit(SIGNAL('currentChanged'), row, col) works just fine. My understanding is that currentChanged is a predefined signal which is why I don't see an overload defned for currentChanged, but I still can't figure out exactly why it is not working if the old code is.

Comment: @AaronTomason. My answer already covers all this. You must define a custom signal if the class does not already define it. Exactly what kind of object is `self`? What is its class? The old-style syntax allowed you to emit signals dynamically (without defining them first), but that is not possibe with the new-style syntax. They **must** be defined if they don't already exist.

Comment: the object is a QWidget. After reading a bit more about QItemSelection, currentChanged is listed as a signal, and since the old code is working as intended, I assumed that defining currentChanged was not necessary, after all the old code is working. I believe this is where I'm lost. I took a look at the QWidget documentation, but didn't see currentChanged listed, it is listed under QTabWidget, but I would image that means the old style still wouldn't work.

Comment: @AaronTomason. As I said in my answer and my previous comment: the old-style syntax allowed emitting undefined signals, but the new-style doesn't. So you **must** define the `currentChanged` signal as I have done in my answer. Can you please try it, and confirm that it works?

Comment: I apologize, I must have overlooked that part of your initial answer, but that completely makes sense now. I will make some changes and get back to you on this. Thanks!

Comment: I was not able to get this to work inside the project I'm working on. Outside of it, it worked just fine. Perhaps my newbie status is my problem in this case. The code I'm working on is above my head, and I'm not quite sure what I need the 'currentChanged' signal to do. Here is a link to the code. Line 133 is the problem child. https://github.com/tomkins/spellcraftcalc/blob/master/MultiTabBar.py This particular file creates a 2 row TabBar. When you comment out line 133, the contents of each tab are no longer updated, the tab changes, but the contents do not. Sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much! Shows that I have a lot to learn, I sincerely appreciate the time you have taken. If I could up vote a few times I would.