# Get valueChanged from qDial to use in method for python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Is it possible to get the valueChanged from a qDial and pass it to another method?  I'm using Sypder 3.2.6 w/ QT deisgner 5.6.2.

My python code goes like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

qtCreatorFile = "testDial.ui" # Enter QT file here.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self) 
    self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.showDialValue)

    def showDialValue(self):
        pass
     #connect to the qDial and print out the new value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = App()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: change `def showDialValue(self):` to  `def showDialValue(self, value): print(value)`

Comment: eyllanesc - passing in the value and print value is what I was looking for.  Thank you for answering.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876880/correct-way-to-convert-old-signal-and-slot-to-new-style

Comment: great much appreciated.