# PyQt4 QtCore.QObject.connect(..., QtCore.SIGNAL(...), ...) into PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt4

I’m translating Yasin’s Model View Video Tutorial Series from PyQt4 into PyQt5. I’m stuck with the following code block:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.uiFilter, QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged(QString)"), self._proxyModel.setFilterRegExp)
```

How shall it be written in PyQt5?

The complete code:

http://www.yasinuludag.com/PyQt/Tutorial05/Tutorial05_ProxyModel.py

The tutorial:

http://discourse.techart.online/t/pyqt-model-view-video-tutorial-series-part-01/1401

Thanks

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876880/correct-way-to-convert-old-signal-and-slot-to-new-style

Comment: `self.uiFilter.textChanged.connect(self._proxyModel.setFilterRegExp)`